# How do you display values in a column as a percentage and add the % sign in oracle sqldeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need help with displaying a column as percentages as well as the % sign on the values in a single column in Oracle SQL developer

The question asked is as follows:

> List all clients who receive a discount on all tours.
>   -- The report should detail, the clients name, their address and the discount they receive as a percentage including a % symbol.

Here is my code so far ( i am new to SQL )

```
SELECT NAME, ADDRESS, DISCOUNT
FROM CLIENT3
WHERE DISCOUNT > 0
```

the table is called client3

Any help would be appreciated
many thanks

Comment: What's the result when you run your query?  In other words, what's the value of discount without using a function?

Comment: In addition to my answer, I just wanted to note that using **NAME** as a column name is slightly problematic.  **NAME** is a keyword in Oracle, and while not a reserved word it could still cause you some issues in the future.  You can get a full list of keywords by running the following `SELECT * FROM v$reserved_words v ORDER BY v.keyword`

Comment: Just to add to @Del comments about problematic column names ... I've been in this business a long time (coming up on 40 years) and am a strong believer in good naming standards.  To that end, I advocate that column names should be at least in the two-part format of  adjective_noun.  For example, in the EMPLOYEE table, not just NAME but FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME.  Not just DATE but HIRE_DATE or BIRTH_DATE.  This will avoid a _lot_ of confusion down the road. Fundamental rule is make names self-documenting.

Answer (score 2):

I went a bit overboard here, but I'll explain:

```sql
WITH client3 (NAME, address, discount) AS
(
  SELECT 'Joe', '123 Main St', 0.25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Tom', '345 Second St', 0.04 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Fred', '587 Third St', 0.155 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT c.name, 
       c.address, 
       TO_CHAR(c.discount*100, 'B90.09')||'%' AS DISCOUNT
FROM client3 c
```

1. I created a CTE with some test data, assuming your discount is stored as decimal number.
2. I multiply the number by 100 to get the percentage
3. I format the number using `TO_CHAR` (This is the overkill part)
4. Concatenate the percent sign on the end to create the string you wanted.